# Regex to validate phone number fails

Tags: javascript, regex

I am trying to valid phone numbers with the following format with a `regex`. But it is failing on certain conditions.

Phone Numbers:

```
2323232
0112323232
011-2323232
+91-9898989898
98989898998
```

I wrote this `regex` for above mentioned numbers:

```
^[+]?(\d{2,4}-)?(\d{7,11})
```

Tested it [here](http://regexr.com?33sck).

I used in the following code segment:

```
var phonePattern = /^[+]?(\d{2,4}-)?(\d{7,11})/;
if(!(phonePattern.test(formData.phone))){
    $('#errorList').append('<li>Invalid Phone Number</li>');
    error = 1;
}
```

The regex works fine for the phone numbers I need, but it also return true for `formData.phone = '011-2323232asdasd'`. I am new to `regex` and its usage in `javascript`. How can I make it work? Please advice.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to put anchors at *both* ends (like `^<a-regex-goes-here>$`, otherwise it will allow rubbish after the match.

Answer (score 1):

Add `$` at the end of your regexp: `^[+]?(\d{2,4}-)?(\d{7,11})$`

It means 'end of text/line', so your regexp will require to have only digits till end of the string.

Answer (score 0):

You need to add an "end with ($)" operator into your code.

```
/^[+]?(\d{2,4}-)?(\d{7,11})$/
```

You may want to take a look at this 
http://www.regular-expressions.info/javascript.html

Answer (score 0):

Try this regex `/^((\+91)?-?[0\+\(]*\d{2,3}[-\s\)]*\.?\d{3,4}[-\s]*\.?[0-9]{4})$/` this will work for all type of valid phone numbers.

Returns true for below conditions:

```
1. Just 10 digits
2. +00 0000 0000
3. +1 000 000 000
4. (3 digits)<space>(3 digits)<space>4 digits
5. (3 digits) - 3 digits - 4 digits
6. +91-9898989898
```

And lot more..

Answer (score 0):

I think you have a missed `$` in the end.
Use:

```
^[+]?(\d{2,4}-)?(\d{7,11})$
```